# How to quantify the anisotropy of a set of points in the plane?

Tags: geometry, statistics, probability-distributions

I have $n$ points in the plane with coordinates $(x_i, y_i)$. What would be a good way to quantify how isotropic/anisotropic their distribution is? I'm thinking of some measure which gives $0$ if $(x_i, y_i)$ are drawn from a radial distribution and $1$ if they are all aligned on a line, so that $x_i = \alpha y_i$.

Edit: the number of points $n$ is not too large so a method using the coordinates directly (rather than binning them first) would be preferable. Also, without loss of generality, let us assume that the origin coincides with the center of mass of the set of points.

Edit2: maybe $\langle |\cos\theta_i| \rangle$ will do the job, where $\theta_i$ is the angle of the position vector of point $i$ with one of the axis. The absolute value is required to keep the orientation.

Comment: Maybe the correlation coefficient will do?

Comment: not really because I want the measure to be invariant to the rotation of the point set. My $<|cos \theta_i|>$ suffers from the same problem, because $<|cos (\theta_i - \theta_0)|>$ depends on $\theta_0$.

Comment: perhaps something along the line of a nematic order tensor would help